# jqGrid fires 'change' event differently when using savekey

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that: 1) uses form editing for rows; 2) has a 'change' listener on one of the fields; and, 3) uses an onClickSubmit callback.

If I change the 'location' field & click the "Submit" button the 'change' event listener fires before onClickSubmit.

If I enable savekey, change the 'location' field & press "Enter" the 'change' event listener fires at the end of my onClickSubmit function when that code manually closes the edit form.

The column def for that field is here:

```
        {name:'location',
            index       :'location',
            width       :120,
            editable    :true,
            edittype    :'text',
            editrules   : {required: true},
            editoptions : {
                size        : 40,
                maxlength   : 400,
                dataEvents  : [{
                    type: 'change',
                    data: { i: $("#grdLocationList").jqGrid("getGridParam")}, 
                    fn  : chC.query.onLocationChange
                }]
            }
        },
```

I then edit the row using the code here:

```
                    $("#grdLocationList").jqGrid("editGridRow",
                        rowid,
                        {
                            onclickSubmit       : onclickSubmitLocal
//                          , savekey               : [true, 13]
                        }
                    );
```

Is there any way to force the pending 'change' event to always fire before my onClickSubmit handler is called?

Comment: The problem is not full clear because you didn't included the code of `chC.query.onLocationChange`. What you do inside? Why it's so important to execute the event *before* `onclickSubmitLocal`? Why you can't just call `chC.query.onLocationChange` (or trigger `change` event) inside of `onclickSubmitLocal` callback?

Comment: onLocationChange makes a synchronous ajax call, retrieves the lat/lon of the address entered into the location field & stores those lat/lon's for use during onClickSubmitLocal. I did try replicate that ajax call in onClickSubmitLocal...but then the location lookup occurred twice (since the change event does eventually fire).